# How to package external .exe files in electron application

Tags: electron, desktop-application, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am developing an electron application where I am using external .exe files. In development mode application works fine.
But when I package the application, it is unable to find those .exe files.

How to include .exe files in packaged application. I am using electron-builder for packaging.

Below is my configuration,

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.f.quickstart",
    "files": [
      "app/build/**/*",
      "app/build/**/*.exe",
      "main.js",
      "mainIPC.js",
      "src/**/*",
      "dist/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "win": {
      "target": "portable",
      "signAndEditExecutable": false
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": "AppImage"
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": "zip"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you found any solution about this

Comment: Please find below my solution,

Added below lines in my package.json

"extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "./binaries/",
        "to": "extraResources",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }

It adds binary files in extraResources folder in dist.
I have kept binaries in './binaries' folder

Comment: @Magnesh Tak thanks

Comment: In my case, I wanted to run the exe's during my app's installation (in order to install some dependencies). I just dropped the exe's directly into my resources folder, which made electron-builder copy them to my dist automatically.

Comment: @ChrisPavs how do you run the exe afterwards?

Comment: @DarrenZou Added [an actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77400249/18032774). Hopefully that helps with your question!

Answer (score 3):

Note that I'm using: `electron ^12.0.0`, `electron-builder ^23.6.0`, and `Windows 11`.

## During Installation

If you only need the exe in your installer, you can just use a `resources` directory. This is useful, for example, when you want to run an exe that installs dependencies during your app's installation.

Here's an example using an nsis installer:

1. Create a `resources` directory in your root directory.
2. Add everything you'll need in the `build` rule:

```js
// package.json

{
...

  "build": {
    "appId": "mycompany.MyProductName",
    "productName": "MyProductName",
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": true
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "extends": null
  }
}
```

3. Create a `vendor` directory within your new `resources` directory.
4. Drag your exe into the `vendor` directory.
5. Create a file called `installer.nsh` within the `resources` directory, and write something like:

```bash
!define vendordir "${BUILD_RESOURCES_DIR}\vendor"

!define myexe_64 "myexe.exe"
!define myexe "myexe_x86.exe"

!macro customInstall
  ${If} ${RunningX64}
    ExecWait '"${vendordir}\${myexe_64}"'
  ${Else}
    ExecWait '"${vendordir}\${myexe}"'
  ${EndIf}
!macroend
```

6. Run the electron builder `dist` command for Windows.

## During Runtime

Using an exe during runtime is such a common use case that I'm honestly surprised how little documentation I could find for this.

Here's an example of how I do it:

1. Create a directory called `extras` anywhere in your project. I put mine at `src/main/extras`.
2. Add an entry for `extraFiles` in your `build` rule:

```js
// package.json

{
...

  "build": {
    "extraFiles": [
      {
        "from": "src/main/extras",
        "to": "extras",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

3. You can now refer to the exe by using the path to your app, but you need to change the path based on development and production. For this, we can use [electron-is-dev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-is-dev):

```js
// preload.js

const { remote } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');

const appPath = remote.app.getAppPath();
const extrasPath = isDev ?
    path.join(appPath, 'src', 'main', 'extras') :
    path.join(appPath, '..', '..', 'extras');

// We finally have our exe!
const exePath = path.join(extrasPath, 'myexe.exe');
```

---

The [Electron Builder configuration docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration) are still a good resource for details.

Hope this helps!